# Trying to insert text into gmail's Search field

Tags: python, selenium, gmail, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to insert text into search field in gmail.com using Selenium (python) but have some problems.

I'm using this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[starts-with(@role, 'search')])")
```

I expected locating object that I can use to apply method send_keys(),
but get error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//input[starts-with(@role, 'search')])"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("q")
```

I would also note that trying to automate Gmail with Selenium is a very bad idea.  I would suggest using GMail's API access instead - https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/